# C Pointer Logic

Tags: c, pointers, struct, dereference, member-access

I have a pointer to a struct that contains a pointer to a short value. The following is the struct.

```c
typedef struct {
  short *val;
} x;
```

If I have a pointer to a variable of type x, I can dereference it and access an element of the struct by doing `x->val`, but since val is a pointer as well, this only gives me the adress of val. How can I dereference this to access the value of val? I tried `*(x->val)`, but that is not working. Or should it work like this, and my mistake has to be something entirely different?

Comment: `*(x->val)` should work, assuming you've initialized the pointer to point to something.

Comment: The struct type is `x`. Do you also have a variable `x *x`? Please create a [mre].

Comment: assuming your `x` is really of type `x`, which itself is odd, *"this only gives me the address of val"* - that is not accurate, and in pointer/dereference land, details *really* matter. It gives you the address *held by `val`*, not the address *of* `val`.  Anyway, you dereference the way you would any other non-void pointer.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are using the structure name in this expression

```
*(x->val)
```

Instead you need to use a pointer to an object of the structure type. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
  short *val;
} x;

int main( void )
{
    short value = 10;
    x obj = { .val = &value };
    x *p = &obj;

    printf( "%d\n", *p->val );
}
```